# Google Apps Script (GAS) - Create ContentService API to serve JSON data from Google Drive

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Still trying to figure out all the new stuff launched at Google IO 2012.  Regarding GAS and ContentService, you are suppose to be able to create an API to serve your content (from Google Drive). A simple example would be like this:

```
var jsonData = {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "age": 25,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
        "city": "New York",
        "state": "NY",
        "postalCode": "10021"
    },
    "phoneNumber": [
        {
            "type": "home",
            "number": "212 555-1234"
        },
        {
            "type": "fax",
            "number": "646 555-4567"
        }
    ]
}

function doGet(e) {

  var output = ContentService.createTextOutput();
  output.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  output.setContent(jsonData);

  return output;

}
```

Then from a normal web page, hopefully using jQuery Ajax, you should be able to get the Json data?

What would the simple javascript code look like on the normal (not-GAS) client?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) to see what it should look like

Also, it should be `output.setContent(JSON.stringify(jsonData));`

Comment: Thanks Cory, even with the change, my super basic sample is still not working. Would you mind posting a simple sample with both GAS and Client JS? Currently my Client JS is:

    $.ajax({
       url: url,
       crossDomain: true,
       dataType:'jsonp',
       cache: false,
       type: 'GET',
       success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
       }    
     })

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really help you with the client side. The apps script part can easily be tested by looking at the result of that URL in a browser.